# Json_decode returns string output

Tags: php, arrays, twitter, json

I am reading json data from a text file. The contents of the file are:

```
{
  "id":"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:181865366610382848",
  "body":"No one wants to carry laptops any more, but we lose IPads and they are not secure. The Sweden PM ran the country for a week on an ipad.",
  "verb":"post",
  "link":"http://twitter.com/ProfNikiEllis/statuses/181865366610382848",
  "generator":{
    "link":"http://twitter.com/#!/download/ipad",
    "displayName":"Twitter for iPad"
  },
  "postedTime":"2012-03-19T22:10:56.000Z",
  "provider":{
    "link":"http://www.twitter.com",
    "displayName":"Twitter",
    "objectType":"service"
  },
  "object":{
    "summary":"No one wants to carry laptops any more, but we lose IPads and they are not secure. The Sweden PM ran the country for a week on an ipad.","id":"object:search.twitter.com,2005:181865366610382848",
    "link":"http://twitter.com/ProfNikiEllis/statuses/181865366610382848",
    "postedTime":"2012-03-19T22:10:56.000Z",
    "objectType":"note"
  }
}
```

My php program reads the contents from the text file and using json_decode gets the individual values. However, json_decode gives me string output instead of array output. Please help!!

```
$file="gist.txt";
//Convert json output to array output
$string = file_get_contents($file);
$json_output = json_decode($string,true);
echo "Check if array: ";
echo is_array($json_output)? "true": "false";echo "<br>";
echo "Check if string: ";
echo is_string($json_output)? "true": "false";echo "<br>";
echo $json_output["id"];
echo $json_output["body"];
echo "***********************************";
```

The output for my program is:

```
Check if array: false
Check if string: true
{{***********************************
```

Comment: What exactly does the output look like?

Comment: `var_dump` your `json_decode` line to see what's happening (and share it with us)

Comment: Either your JSON having been "stringified" in the file for whatever reason, or your example is not the code that actually runs. `$json_output["id"]` (and `["body"]`) are indexing into the string, the indexes `id` and `body` are converted to integer `0` as per the usual rules and you see the opening brace of JSON-in-a-string twice.

Comment: @Jon how do i avoid the json from being stringified?

Comment: @user2998027: Find the code responsible for doing that and remove it. Not much help but that really is what you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there seems to be a problem with the json code in the file.
I shortened the contents of the file and now the code works.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code locally and it's running as expected for me:

```
Check if array: true
Check if string: false
```

Run this and tell us what you're getting, it might be a permissions thing:

```
$string = file_get_contents($file);
var_dump($string);
```

It should output the contents of the file if it opened successfully, or a self explanitory PHP error if it fails.

Comment: This is the output i get for var_dump

string(3596) "{ "id":"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:181865366610382848", "body":"No one wants to carry laptops any more, but we lose IPads and they are not secure. The Sweden PM ran the country for a week on an ipad.", "verb":"post", "link":"http://twitter.com/ProfNikiEllis/statuses/181865366610382848", "generator":{ "link":"http://twitter.com/#!/download/ipad", "displayName":"Twitter for iPad" }, "postedTime":"2012-03-19T22:10:56.000Z"}"